# TFS 2010 Build of Web application creates multiple DLL's

Tags: asp.net, deployment, dll, msbuild

I am having a serious problem with TFS build.  When we publish the website through visual studio 2010 the Web Site becomes a single dll in the bin directory where we publish it.  When we use the build tool in TFS it splits that single DLL into numerous smaller DLL's with strange names which include some hash code and the aspx file name.  I suspected that it is was that is was an old web site first created in VS 2005 and then migrated over so what I did was convert the project into a Empty web application and then migrate everything over.

After about three hours of work and debugging, I got the conversion to compile and run.  I did a publish with VS 2010 and it converted over to a single DLL inside the bin directory and it ran.  When I used TFS build, it did the same thing spliting the file into numerous DLL's.  HELP!

If VS can create a project with a single DLL what are we doing wrong with TFS build to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

TFS Build does **not** do anything more special than running msbuild to build and publish your projects. If I were you, I would try the following things:

1. Make sure the project files from your dev box and from the build machine are the same.
2. Open the TFS build log and get the msbuild command there. Try running it locally on your dev box against your local projects and see if the behavior is the same or difference. There's a good chance that you'll get the same result as running on the build machine. If that's the case, now you can repro the problem locally and you would need to figure out the cause, then fix the build definition to run the correct msbuild command.
3. If running the same msbuild command gives you differen results on different machines, check the msbuild versions on both machine, check the msbuild log files (you can get the TFS build's msbuild log from the drop location of the build, or from a link in the build details view in VS), and if possible, jump on the build machine to see if you can repro the problem yourself running the same msbuild command.

I've investigated a few build issues this way it works for me most of the time, so I thought I'd share it. Let me know how far you'll get and I can help further.

Good luck!